# Get the name of the weekday on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I compute the name of the day like this:

```
func loadDayName(forDate date: NSDate) -> String{
    let myComponents = calendar.components(.Weekday, fromDate: date)
    let weekDay = myComponents.weekday
    switch weekDay {
    case 1:
        return "Sunday"
    case 2:
        return "Monday"
    case 3:
        return "Tuesday"
    case 4:
        return "Wednesday"
    case 5:
        return "Thursday"
    case 6:
        return "Friday"
    case 7:
        return "Saturday"
    default:
        return "Nada"
    }
}
```

It is working fine but I was wondering if Swift comes with some libraries to do that automatically.

Comment: You should use NSDateFormatter with a custom date format.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/dateFormat

Comment: @Darren i already do that but that has nothing to do with the question that is why i didn't show you the code for it

Comment: You can configure a date formatter to print just the full day name for a given NSDate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27369380/2303865

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question is more broad. This is the best question for this specific question and answer.

Comment: I agree with Joshua that this is not a duplicate question

Answer (score 109):

Use `DateFormatter`

Swift 4

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Swift3

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat  = "EEEE" // "EE" to get short style
let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date) // "Sunday"
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: it is a good option, but the array contains  `["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]` not full name for days like i want

Comment: With `shortWeekdaySymbols `,you can get short String.Like the code I update

Comment: how did you know that weekdaysSymbols contain the full names? i printed it, both of them contain the short name. +1 for the efforts

Comment: The `weekdaysSymbols` just works well on my playground. You can also use dateFormatter.Like the code I update

Comment: In Swift 4 the stringFromDate is now `formatter.string(from: now)`

Comment: Make sure you also set the `locale` for the `dateFormatter` if you care about i18n.

Comment: From https://nsdateformatter.com There isn't an ```EE``` option. ````EEEEE```` gets ```MTWTFSS``` and ```EEEEEE``` gets ```MoTuWeThFrSaSu```

Answer (score 24):

If you want to get the array of day names you could use: `weekdaySymbols in Calendar()`

example:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let days = calendar.weekdaySymbols
```

Comment: Yes, but right after you set the `calendar.locale`.

Answer (score 5):

There's a new api since iOS 15.

```swift
@available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
extension FormatStyle where Self == Date.FormatStyle {

    public static var dateTime: Date.FormatStyle { get }
}
```

You can now use:

```swift
Date().formatted(.dateTime.month(.wide)) // October
Date().formatted(.dateTime.year(.defaultDigits)) // 2022
Date().formatted(.dateTime.weekday(.wide)) // Thursday
Date().formatted(.dateTime.weekday(.abbreviated)) // Thu
Date().formatted(.dateTime.weekday(.narrow)) // T
```

and so on and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can check also this DateFormatter

```
let dayNameFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = .current
    dateFormatter.calendar = .current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "cccc"
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

```
print(dayNameFormatter.string(from: Date())) Prints today's day name
```

`c` - stands for day of the week, [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909056/6057764), [official source](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)